# How to know when React Bootstrap modal has been loaded?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-hooks, use-effect

I've built a modal with React Bootstrap that generally works fine. But when the browser is zoomed in, an inner `div` scrolls down a little, obscuring the top of the modal.  So I added a `useEffect` to scroll back to the top when the modal is loaded.  I was able to accomplish this in my functional React component like this:

```
  // A reference to a `div` at the top of my modal
  // Note: This approach won't work: const titleRef = useRef(null);
  const titleRef = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (titleRef.current) {
      const modalBodyContainer = document.getElementById('modalBodyContainer');
      if (modalBodyContainer) {
        modalBodyContainer.scrollTop = 0;
      }
    }
  }, [titleRef]);
```

I need to add some more code so it's only run once, when first loaded but it otherwise does work correctly.

But I'm wondering if there's another way than using a `ref` in the way I have?

Comment: There are a number of lifecycle events that React Bootstrap documents for the modal, you're probably looking for `onShow` or `onEntered` or the like https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-props

Comment: @djfdev : `onEntered` was precisely what I needed.  Thank you!

Can I ask you a follow-up question:  This code causes an error with too many re-renders:
```<Modal onEntered={setIsLoaded(true)}>```

Whereas this code works perfectly:
```<Modal onEntered={e => setIsLoaded(true)}>```

What about the fat arrow function fixes the problem?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I know.  If specifying a function directly, it's important not to call it - ie. `setIsLoaded` instead of `setIsLoaded()`.  So the fact that I need to pass the `true` parameter to it means that I need to write it in the fat-arrow syntax that I did.  Correct?

Comment: I don’t know what your setIsLoaded function does, but I would guess that it does not return a function. In the first case, you are using the return value of setIsLoaded as the event handler. In the other case, you’re using it in the body of an event handler. Likely has nothing to do with the arrow function, but instead the fact you’re actually using a function to define onEntered.